# How to use if else in ajax post after success post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to use if else in ajax post after success post ?

in this code , after success post i want to check `var track` and `var total`

if `track != total` i want to `$('#button').show();`

But now work

How can i do ?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").click(function(e){
        var track = 3;
        var total = 3;
        $('#button').hide();
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'page.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#xxxx').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                if(track != total)
                  {
                    $('#button').show();
                  }

                    $("#results").append(data);
                }
            }
         )
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the response of your ajax request?

Comment: The condition would never be true, you're never changing `track` or `total` so they are always the  same

Comment: are you expecting track and total to be attributes of the data? If so, you'll need to dig deeper into the returned data

Comment: @  PHP Weblineindia not have any data in `append()`

Comment: @nomwery geqoilu does your data variable content "track" and "total"?

Comment: `var track = 3;`
        `var total = 3;`

Comment: And `if ( 3 != 3 )` is never true, should be easy to grasp ?

Comment: @  adeneo , i will only to check condition.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i see that you attach click event listener to #button and next you show it after ajax complete.

Is this the same button?

Open inspector and in the network section check the response of your request, if you have some error(s)
the 'success' function will not be called.

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").click(function(e){
          var total_click = 3;
          var page = 3;

          $('#button').hide();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'page.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: $('#xxxx').serialize(),
              cache: false,
              success: function (data) {
                  if(track != total) {
                      $('#button').show();
                  }

                  $("#results").append(data);
              }
          }).error(function(err) {
              console.error(err); //This will output something
          });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will help you :**

```
function check() {
var abc = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var xyz = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'first_name=' + abc + '&last_name=' + xyz;

// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
alert(success);
}
});
return false;
}
```

Here, **alert** will generate if your request will be successfull.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it this way, you need to pass your variables in your page.php, and then access them through  your data parameter.

If you want to pass multiple parameters through "data", you can use json_encode in your page.php, and then access in your ajax with data.your_variable. (Not sure of the exact way, you might have to look that up)